# Querying a deep child object with a certain property, but returning the root object which cascades down

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Sorry about the cryptic heading, I have always struggled with this problem.

Say we have a model structure like so:
**Schools**, which have **classes**, which in turn have **students**. I'd like to return a list of schools (as the top-level object), including classes and students where the students are male.

The easy way to do this would be:

```
var maleStudents = Context.Students
  .Include(s => s.Classes)
  .ThenInclude(c => c.School)
  .Where(s => s.Gender == Gender.Male)
```

Problem is, this returns a bunch of students with their own duplicate copies of the classes and schools. It also makes it hard to visually display them via 'School' without a bunch of organizing.

Is there an elegant solution or does it require my usual juggle after pulling it all to the server?

Comment: "_with their own duplicate copies of the classes_" No, each class will be a single instance, and each student within that class will hold a reference to that same instance. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Assuming each student's classes all belong to the same school, it should be as simple as `maleStudents.GroupBy(x => x.Classes.First().School)`.

Comment: To put it simply, instead of returning a list of students who match criteria (which have classes and school filled), I want a list of schools, with classes and then students.

School as the top-level object. For example something like this would solve it, but is not allowed:
var schools = Context.Schools.Include(s => s.Classes).ThenInclude(c => c.Students /* Where student.gender == Male*/);

Comment: The functionality you're after has been introduced in [EF Core v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include), but until then the `GroupBy` above should do the job.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay This is almost perfect, and good enough for my purposes. If you'd like to make your reply an answer I'll mark it so. 'Filtered Include' looks great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of EF Core 5.0, [filtered includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) are supported, so you could write your query as follows:

```
var schools = Context.Schools
    .Include(s => s.Classes)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.Students.Where(s => s.Gender == Gender.Male));
```

If your targeting previous versions of EF Core your existing query is fine, as you could perform a `GroupBy` in the client to project your structure:

```
var schoolsWithStudents = maleStudents
  .GroupBy(x => x.Classes
  .First().School);
```

Although this assumes that each student only belongs to classes relating to the same school.

---

**Update after comment**

If you only want to bring back schools that have Male students, you can add an extra `Where` after the filtered include:

```
var schools = Context.Schools
    .Include(s => s.Classes)
    .ThenInclude(c => c.Students.Where(s => s.Gender == Gender.Male))
    .Where(s => s.Classes.Any(c => c.Students.Any(st => st.Gender == Gender.Male)));
```

Comment: After experimentation, 'Filtered Includes' is not a perfect match as it will return all schools, regardless of if the students match. Still, a welcome change. For now, GroupBy remains the winner.